# Using db2 odbc parameters with Timestamp C#

Tags: c#, db2, odbc, db2-luw

I am trying to use parameters for a DB2 query using ODbc in C#, but the Timestamp field is giving me issues.  I am using DB2 Client 9.7 and updateDate is a DateTime type.  Here is my code:

```
string commandString = "INSERT INTO DATABASENAME(USERNAME, UPDATE_DATE) VALUES ('?', TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('?', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))";

OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString);
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(commandString, con);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", userName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?update_date", updateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

//execute the stuff
con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
ERROR [42815] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0171N  The data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine "SYSIBM.TIMESTAMP_FORMAT" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815
```

I have also tried using the regular TIMESTAMP() function included in DB2 using both formats it accepts (Ex. TIMESTAMP ('2016-10-20-12.00.00.000000') 
TIMESTAMP ('2016-10-20 12:00:00')), but that gives me this error:

```
ERROR [22007] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

EDIT: It works without using parameters, can parameters not be used with DB2?

Comment: You convert `updateDate`, which is a DateTime, to string in your C# code, then try to convert it back to timestamp in the SQL statement. Why not supply the parameter as DateTime?

Comment: @mustaccio Changing my parameter to something like this? command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?update_date", updateDate);  When I have tried that, I am receiving the error of "an invalid datetime format was decected, an invalid string representaiton was specified."  In my command string, I also changed my updateDate to be a regular parameter instead of a string ? vs. '?' with still no luck either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no way of testing this but I think you should not enclose parameter markers in quotes, they are parameters, not literals. Your statement should look like

```
string commandString = "INSERT INTO DATABASENAME(USERNAME, UPDATE_DATE) VALUES (?,?)";
```

and then you also won't need double conversion from `DateTime` to string to `TIMESTAMP`:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", userName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?update_date", updateDate);
```

Comment: When i try this, I get this error, my string value is also not too large for the chars allowed. `ERROR [22001] [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0109E  String data right truncation. SQLSTATE=22001`

Comment: Whoops, I had messed up my ordering of my parameter assignments.  That fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: @Esperento57 Yup! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

may be an error on timestamp format.

Try to do updateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.ss.ffffff"));

Comment: I tried your suggestion and had to change my Timestamp function as well to this: TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('?', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:NNNNNN').  I still am receiving my original error of "Arument 1 is incorrect format."

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
string commandString =string.format("INSERT INTO DATABASENAME(USERNAME, UPDATE_DATE) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')", userName, updateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.ss.ffffff"));

OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString);
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(commandString, con);

//execute the stuff
con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: It still gave me an error, but switching it to `updateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` works.  Why can't I do this using parameters?

Comment: Happy, its work, like i thaught the probleme is a conversion of format string passed to TIMESTAMP_FORMAT or how you pass your parameter

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know why I can't use parameters to do this same thing though?

Comment: May be with this syntax: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dec_col FROM MYTABLE WHERE dec_col > ? ";
OdbcParameter p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
p1.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
p1.Value = 10.0;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  Add your parameter, modify type correctly and value.

Comment: If he dont work, put type of parameter timestamp like string or Ansistring

Comment: I have put a new solution with parameter if you want test

Answer (score 0):

```
        string commandString = "INSERT INTO DATABASENAME(USERNAME, UPDATE_DATE) VALUES ('?','?')";

        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString);
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(commandString, con);

        OdbcParameter p1 = command.CreateParameter();
        p1.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
        p1.Value = userName;
        command.Parameters.Add(p1);

        OdbcParameter p2 = command.CreateParameter();
        p2.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
        p2.Value = updateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        command.Parameters.Add(p2);


        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Still gives the same error for the updateDate.  I have tried all the DBTypes involving Date as well. `ERROR [22007] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007`  It's like ODbc isn't putting parameters in correctly.

Comment: Yes ODBC has problem, i use idb2command in general with c# .net . And if you try with this code and updateDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.ss.ffffff"));   ??